# Leave one out cross validation in matlab

Tags: matlab, svm

Can you help me how to use leave one out cross validation in Matlab? Because the data that I used is small. I use 10 data training for true positive and 10 data training for false positive. I tried code that I found in here. This is my training function:

```
Function [ C,F ] = classification_test_samesize()

    dn='D:\thesis\mthesis\code program\FalsePositive\'
    db=dir(strcat(dn,'*.dcm'));
    F=[];
    C=[];

    for(i=1:1:length(db))
        name=db(i).name;
        name=strcat(dn,name);
        im1=dicomread(name);
        [out] = func_feature(im1);
        f = [out];
        F = [F;f];
        C=[C;-1];

    end

    % false positive is -1 th class


    dn='D:\thesis\mthesis\code program\TruePositive\'
    db=dir(strcat(dn,'*.dcm'));

    for(i=1:1:length(db))
        name=db(i).name;
        name=strcat(dn,name);
        im1=dicomread(name);
        [out] = func_feature(im1);
        f = [out];
        F = [F;f];
        C=[C;1];
        % true positive is 1 th class
    end
end
```

and this is my main function.

```
clc

direktori= uigetdir;
slash = '\';
direktori=strcat(direktori,slash);
dn=direktori;
db=dir(strcat(dn,'*.dcm'));
ftest=[];

for(i=1:1:length(db))
    name=db(i).name;
    name=strcat(dn,name);

    im1=dicomread(name);
    [out] = func_feature(im1);
    f = [out];
    ftest = [ftest;f];
end

[C,F] = classification_test_samesize();
svmStruct = svmtrain(F,C,'showplot',true,'Kernel_Function','rbf');
result_class = svmclassify(svmStruct,ftest,'showplot',true);
```

In my main function I called testing folder to test the data. but in this case, I want to use leave one out cross validation for testing data, so I am not called the directory again. Can you help me to solve this? So, I can use one of training data to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my first example left you confused, I took another look at your complete code, and I think I have a simpler way to achieve what you want.  First, here is the classification function: it looks a lot like the original, but I'm not trying to take any data out - instead, we'll select a number of data points AFTER the calculation:

```
Function [ C,F ] = classification_test_samesize(fpDir, tpDir)
% compute the C and F for files in the two directories given
db=dir(fullfile(fpDir,'*.dcm')); % preferred to strcat
F=[];
C=zeros(numel(db), 1);
%
% don't use 'i' as variable name - it is built in, and means "sqrt(-1)"
for ii= 1:numel(db)
    name=fullfile(fpDir, db(ii).name); % the correct way to concatenate directory and file name
    im1=dicomread(name);
    % I would like to think you could pre-allocate size for F
    % and use F(ii)=func_feature(im1); directly?
    F = [F; func_feature(im1)];
    C(ii) = -1;   
    fprintf(1, 'file name: %s; class -1\n', db(ii).name); 
end

% false positive is -1 th class

db=dir(fullpath(tpDir,'*.dcm'));
%
for ii = 1:numel(db)
    im1=dicomread(fullfile(tpDir, db(ii).name);
    F = [F; func_feature(im1)];
    C = [C;1];
    fprintf(1, 'file name: %s; class 1\n', db(ii).name);
% true positive is 1 th class
end
end
```

You call this function with the two parameters corresponding to the true negative and true positive directory - at which point you have all the calculations done. Now you can choose which of these data you will use for training, and which for testing.

```
clc    
% pick the number of the file we are using for test instead of training:

[C,F] = classification_test_samesize('D:\thesis\mthesis\code program\FalsePositive\', ...
    'D:\thesis\mthesis\code program\TruePositive\');

% now we are going to pick some of these for training, and others for verification
numTest = 5; % whatever number you want to set aside for verification
% >>>> changed the next three lines <<<<
randomIndx = randperm(1:numel(C));
testVal = randomIndx(1:numTest);
trainingSet = randomIndex(numTest+1:end);

% do the training: this uses those elements from F and C which are chosen for training:
Ctrain = C(trainingSet);
Ftrain = F(trainingSet);

disp('The following values now exist in "C":')
display(unique(Ctrain)); % this is to confirm there are exactly two classes...

svmStruct = svmtrain(Ftrain,Ctrain,'showplot',true,'Kernel_Function','rbf');

% finally, classify the other values:
result_class = svmclassify(svmStruct,F(testVal),'showplot',true);
```

I hope you can take it from here...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. but I'm very beginner in matlab. I am still confused how to called the function im my main that have been corrected by you. because i have to put two parameters that is leaveOutFP and leaveOutTP. I hope u can help me to solve this.. thank you

Comment: there's some error when i run it 

"Error using svmtrain (line 335)
Y must contain exactly two groups for method 'SMO'.

Error in main (line 15)
svmStruct = svmtrain(Ftrain,Ctrain,'showplot',true,'Kernel_Function','rbf');


do you have any idea to solve it? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Please check what the size of `Ctrain` is, and what values are in it. I expect it to be a column vector with only `1` and `-1` in it - if that's not what happened we need to figure out why not. By the way I discovered a possible problem in computing the `testVal` - as written you could get repeated values. I am going to update that code now.

Comment: I tried to run ur code but there's some error again :

> In main2 at 10 
Undefined function or variable 'numVal'.

Error in main2 (line 11)
testVal = randomIndex(1:numVal);

how to fix it?

Comment: Typo - should have been `numTest`. Sorry!

Comment: Ctrain is column vector with the value  1 1 1 1 1 and the size is 5x1 double. can u help me to solve this??? thank you

Comment: I've changed it . and error again 

In main2 at 10 
11  testVal = randomIndex(1:numTest);
Undefined function 'randomIndex' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in main2 (line 11)
testVal = randomIndex(1:numTest);

Comment: Look at the line above - I had called it `randomIndx` there and `randomIndex` in the line below. Change them to have the same name.

Comment: Ok.. but I got some error again:

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in main2 (line 11)
testVal = randomIndx(1:numTest);

Comment: Set `numTest=1` and try again. How many files are there in your directories? Did you try running the most recently edited code - which prints out the names of the files as they are being processed? You should have some `1` and some `-1` in Ctrain... I don't have your data, and limited time to hold your hand. Do try to understand what the code does instead of just saying "it doesn't work"!

Comment: `randomIndx` is an array of indices in random order - in a sense we "shuffled" the data points. `testVal` is then the "first five elements" (think of it as the first five cards from a shuffled deck), and `trainingSet` is "the rest of the deck" (starting at `numTest+1`, and finishing at `end` - the last element). If you print these two variables out you will see what I mean.

Comment: Iam still confused in this part 
testVal = randomIndx(1:numTest);
trainingSet = randomIndx(numTest+1:end);

testVal is variable to define data testing but why use randomIndx? because it's a previous variable and will get the result "Index exceeds matrix dimensions". and when i print randomIndx(numTest+1:end)

ans =

   Empty matrix: 1-by-0

Comment: What is `numel(C)`? I am assuming that you have a reasonable number of elements in C. It is better to pick your validation points at random, which is why I shuffle the values and pick (e.g. 5) at random for validation, whilst keeping the rest for the training. What output did you get from the code I edited earlier - you should see the names of all the files being processed. That should give you a pretty good clue...

Comment: Iam still can not solve this problem . 

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in main2 (line 11)
testVal = randomIndx(1:numTest);

do you have any idea?

Comment: Ok, the problem is my feature has multidirectional feature, so I have to put Ctrain = C(trainingSet,:);
Ftrain = F(trainingSet,:); and it's working. thank you.

Comment: I am glad you were able to figure it out!